# Is it possible to use Puppeteer to convert PDF to HTML?

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, puppeteer, headless-browser

I know that it's possible the other way(HTML to PDF), but can it be done the other way?

I didn't find any documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Puppeteer cannot be used on converting PDF to HTML. According to its website:

> Puppeteer is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol.

That is, Puppeteer is a headless Chrome. As Chrome cannot convert PDF to HTML (please correct me if I'm wrong), neither can Puppeteer.

However, you can use other npm modules, such as [pdf-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse) to parse the text content of PDF, and generating the HTML by yourself. Or, just use npm modules such as [pdf2html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2html) to convert pdf directly.